# How to read the disk usage (du) in a C variable

Tags: c++

I would like to do the following in a "c" program.

I need to get the disk usage of the following directory and should be able to read it in a variable.

```
du -sb /home/mann | awk '{print$1}'
```

I would like to do the above in C program and copy the output in a variable. I need to do this for this directory alone not for the "/" or "/home".

Comment: Sounds like a Systems Programming homework assignment.

Comment: To get good answers, you're going to have to refine your question. You said you can't use `system` (and presumably also not popen/pclose) so it sounds like you *don't* want to run `du` within a C program, but rather write something yourself that does what it does? Do you have other restrictions? Any ideas to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Pipe the output of your command to a file on the disk. Run your command using **[system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/)**
- Read the file using standard C functions
- Update your variable

Another option is to use **[popen/pclose](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)** to launch your command. This will return a file descriptor from which you can read.

Yet another option is to hunt your system for any library function that provides the information you desire

Comment: I need to do this inside the c code. How do I do that? I can't use "system" call.